# Multi threading IO tasks in python doesnt help performance in my case

Tags: python, multithreading, io, python-multithreading

I have a list of files I need to read from. However, reading them all takes awhile. I tried using the threading library, but it doesn't seem to help.

```
def readFromLog():
    #does something with log files

def singleThreadReader(logFiles):
    for i in range(len(logFiles)):
        readFromLog(logFiles[i])

def multiThreadReader(logFiles):
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=readFromLog, args=(log_file,)) for log_file in logFiles]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

For example, I have 26 files. It takes about 0.3 seconds for readFromLog() to do its thing with a single file. So it takes about 7.8 (26*0.3) seconds for me to read through all 26 files. This is what I see when I call singleThreadReader(). When I call multiThreadReader, I also get comparable execution times as singleThreadReader(). I do notice that if I take out the thread.joins, the time is cut in half, but I don't think I want to be doing that.

What could I be doing wrong? It would be ideal if I can have all 26 files read at the same time - execution time being 0.3 seconds total.

Comment: If all of the files are on the same hard drive, then using multiple threads to read them probably will not help the hard drive to go any faster.

Comment: What exactly are you timing? If dropping the joins causes the time to be cut in half, it sounds like you're just timing how long it takes to start all the threads.